# is possible {grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, (auto, auto));}?

Tags: css, css-grid

when I use:

```
grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(420px, 1fr));
```

all work fine, but each COLUMN have width fixed in 420px.

I need width = auto (based in content), then When I use

```
grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, 1fr));
```

or

```
grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min-content, 1fr));
```

not work.

How I can define width for columns as "min-content" or "auto" ?

this is my web page:

```css
.tabmag {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(420px, 1fr));
  border: 1px solid;
}

.tabmag figure {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="tabmag">
  <figure>UNO</figure>
  <figure>DOS</figure>
  <figure>TRES</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>CUATRO CUATRO CUATRO</figure>
  <figure>CINCO</figure>
  <figure>DIÉZ</figure>
  <figure>ONCE</figure>
</main>
```

Comment: you cannot do this with auto-fit and minmax()

Comment: what option I can use?

Comment: What is this supposed to look like?

Comment: What is this supposed to look like?

Comment: thanks by your help @Paulie_D, this is my target/focus: https://pasteboard.co/odLNTD6LmjlO.png ( you can see, width not is fixed, is dynamic.